# What's the difference between normal viscous stress and pressure?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

The stress tensor on a fluid element is the following:
[image]

The diagonal terms in the two tensors $-p\textbf{I}$ and $2\mu\textbf{e}$ are both stresses that act perpendicular to the faces of the fluid element. But there must be a reason why they've been separated into two, namely pressure and normal viscous stress. From a molecular point of view, what's the difference between pressure and normal viscous stress?

Comment: In the form you have written the equations, it is inherently assumed that the fluid is incompressible.  For an incompressible fluid, the state of stress is determined up to an arbitrary isotropic stress, which is embodied in the pressure.  The value of the pressure is determined by the loading conditions at the boundary of the system.